Suppose that $V$ is a vector space and let $u,v,w\in V$, such that $span(u,v)=span(u,w)$. Then $V=kw$ for some $k$.
The question is to prove or disprove, given the above, that $v=kw$ for some number $k$.
What I did to try and solve it is assume that $v=ku$, i.e. $v$ is spanned by $u$, and then assumed that $w=0$. This would mean that $span(u,v)=span(u,w)$, however $v$ is not equal to $kw$.
Is there an error in my logic or it is correct?

Consider the vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$, then
$$span \left(\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 0\\1\end{pmatrix}\right)=span \left(\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 1\\1\end{pmatrix}\right)$$
but certainly there does not exist a scalar $k\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$\begin{pmatrix} 0\\1\end{pmatrix}=k\begin{pmatrix} 1\\1\end{pmatrix}.$$
So this is a counterexample. Why would you assume that $u$ and $v$ are collinear?

Thank you. Yeah I know, but what i assumed also works as a coutnerexample right?

Ah, now I understand Your point. Yes of course if $u=v\neq 0$ and $w=0$ You get a very general counterexample. Actually over every field. +1

So the real answer should be: No error in Your logic.

Thank you for your help!

You´re welcome!
